# Conditional inside map() doesn't work as intended (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{user.anotherUser.followers &&
  user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => {
    if (user.user._id === a._id) {
      return console.log("following button");
    } else {
      return console.log("follow button");
    }
})}
```

Data:

```
{
  "username": "John",
  "followers": [],
}
```

The problem is that `return console.log("follow button");` **does not run** when the followers array is empty.

When the array is not empty, the `return console.log("following button")` successfully runs which is good.

When not empty, the `followers` array contains objects of different users (populated it on the backend to access ObjectID properties) like this:

```
{
  "username": "John",
  "followers": [
     "_id": "123123123",
     "username": "David"
  ],
}
```

What did I do wrong?

The `user.user._id` is my id which is `123123123` in this case.

**EDIT:**

```
       {user.anotherUser.followers &&
        user.anotherUser.followers.length > 0 ? (
            user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => {
                if (user.user._id === a._id) {
                    return <Button>Following</Button>;
                } else {
                    return <Button>Follow</Button>;
                }
            })
        ) : (
            <Button>Follow</Button>
        )}
```

With this, both `Following` and `Follow` buttons are displayed. Only one button should be display by logic.

**EDIT2:**

```
       {user.anotherUser.followers &&
        user.anotherUser.followers.length > 0 ? (
            user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => {
                if (user.user._id === a._id) {
                    return <Button>Following</Button>;
                }
            })
        ) : (
            <Button>Follow</Button>
        )}
```

Now the `Follow` button does not appear if the `length > 0`, because **someone else's** `id` is in the array, although mine (`user.user._id`) is not there. The `Follow` button should appear if the array `length > 0` and if my `user.user._id` is not inside it either.

**EDIT3:**

I could use a different approach because `user.user` has a `following` array field in the database.

```
let userFollowing =
  user.user.following && user.user.following.map((a) => a._id);
```

And then display one button like this:

```
            {user.user.following &&
                userFollowing.includes(user.anotherUser._id) && (
                    <Button className="follow-true">Following</Button>
                )}
            {user.user.following &&
                !userFollowing.includes(user.anotherUser._id) && (
                    <Button className="follow-false">Follow</Button>
                )}
```

**EDIT4:** better and final solution:

Above the `return()`

```
let anotherUserFollowers =
        user.anotherUser.followers &&
        user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => a._id);
```

In the `return()`

```
           {user.anotherUser.followers &&
                anotherUserFollowers.includes(user.user._id) && (
                    <Button
                        onClick={() =>
                            props.follow({
                                id: user.anotherUser._id,
                            })
                        }
                        className="follow-true"
                    >
                        Following
                    </Button>
                )}
            {user.anotherUser.followers &&
                !anotherUserFollowers.includes(user.user._id) && (
                    <Button
                        onClick={() =>
                            props.follow({
                                id: user.anotherUser._id,
                            })
                        }
                        className="follow-false"
                    >
                        Follow
                    </Button>
                )}
```

Comment: using in JSX? If yes than you've to return JSX there because it requires JSX to render and convert to HTML. Another thing you can't map empty array.

Comment: But I think I do `return` it in the conditional, and yes this is in the JSX

Comment: @David empty arrays can't be mapped.

Answer (score 2):

You can return early if there are no followers, optional chaining helps make this easier:

```
if (!user?.anotherUser?.followers?.length) return <Button>Follow</Button>

return user.anotherUser.followers.map(a =>
 (user.user._id === a._id) ? <Button>Following</Button> : <Button>Follow</Button>);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map` executes the given function *for each element in the array*

That means if your array does not have any elements in your array, no code will be executed. And that's the expected behaviour.

If you want to do something when the array is empty, you should do something else outside the `.map` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **you just set a condition on your JSX like `user.anotherUser.followers && ...` so whenever you got `"followers": []`, the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) won't run, on the other hand, if the condition doesn't block the `Array#map` execution it won't run either**, because you can't do a map over an empty array.

Here is an example for more illustration:

```js
const arr = [];

const newArr = arr.map(el => console.log('first console', el))
console.log('second console', newArr)
```

So to fix this you can implement it in some other way like ternary operation.

```js
const user = {
  anotherUser: {
    followers: []
  }
};

(user.anotherUser.followers && user.anotherUser.followers.length > 0 && user.user._id) ?
user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => {
    if (user.user._id === a._id) {
      console.log("following button");
    }
  }):
  console.log("No followers found!");
```

Comment: I made another edit for this one. I'm trying to solve it. I think this is another small issue, not really related to the original question.

Comment: @David If you just want to check if `user.user._id` in your array exist or not you can chain another simple condition to your ternary condition like this like this: `(user.anotherUser.followers && user.anotherUser.followers.length > 0 && user.user._id) ? ...`

Comment: I used another approach but I will try this one too. See my edit (that's working).

Comment: @David Optional chaining is very Good and useful but you need a polyfill for it since the support coverage does not include old browsers. Also as you said earlier your second question was different from the OP and my first answer covered the OP. So I hope you mark this one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Above the return()

```
let anotherUserFollowers =
        user.anotherUser.followers &&
        user.anotherUser.followers.map((a) => a._id);
```

In the return()

```
       {user.anotherUser.followers &&
            anotherUserFollowers.includes(user.user._id) && (
                <Button
                    onClick={() =>
                        props.follow({
                            id: user.anotherUser._id,
                        })
                    }
                    className="follow-true"
                >
                    Following
                </Button>
            )}
        {user.anotherUser.followers &&
            !anotherUserFollowers.includes(user.user._id) && (
                <Button
                    onClick={() =>
                        props.follow({
                            id: user.anotherUser._id,
                        })
                    }
                    className="follow-false"
                >
                    Follow
                </Button>
            )}
```